# Offline with Bots?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there any way for me to directly modify how many players are on each team for CS:GO? I don't have a very good computer, and the default 5v5 makes running CS:GO a real pain.  I'd really like to only start out with 3v3s, realisticlly, but I don't know how to modify server settings.

What should I do to make offline with bots a lot easier on my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this, namely editing config files.  However, the easiest way is for you to use console commands once you are in a game to fill it however you like.  You will start with a standard 5 vs 5 setup and by using the following commands you can then clear the server and fill it with the amount of bots you so desire.

> 1. **bot_kick** - This command will remove all bots from the game.
> 2. **bot_quota #** - By replacing the "#" with a number you will spawn in that amount of bots.  Take into account that YOU are included in that number.  For instance if you type "bot_quota 2" it will simply add 1 bot in addition to yourself.

You can find additional bot-related console commands [HERE](http://wiki.multiplay.co.uk/CSGO/Bot_Commands).